# The output of Spark DataFrame replace column names with "0", "1" when arrays_zip data originated nested

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I used spark sql functions arrays_zip combined with flatten to transform data from array of struct of inner array of the same length  into array of struct.  printSchema shows exactly I want.  However, df output lost original column names and replace them with generic column name "0", "1", "2" etc. no matter in Parquet or Avro format.   I like to output original column names.

Not to reveal the business of my company.   The followings are similar but much simplified examples.

```
scala> c2.printSchema
root
 |-- cal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- month: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- num: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
scala> c2.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------+
|cal                                           |
+----------------------------------------------+
|[[[Jan, Feb, Mar], [1, 2, 3]], [[April], [4]]]|
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I like to transform to

```
scala> newC2.show(false)
+------------------------------------------+
|cal                                       |
+------------------------------------------+
|[[Jan, 1], [Feb, 2], [Mar, 3], [April, 4]]|
+------------------------------------------+
with
scala> newC2.printSchema
root
 |-- cal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true)
```

I know arrays_zip only work well on the top-level arrays.  Therefore, I flatten them to top level. The followings codes work in this example

```
val newC2 = c2.withColumn("month", flatten(col("cal.month"))).withColumn("num", flatten(col("cal.num"))).withColumn("cal", arrays_zip(col("month"), col("num"))).drop("month", "num")
```

It generates exactly data and schema I want.  However, it outputs all columns generically using "0", "1", "2" etc.

```
newC2.write.option("header", false).parquet("c2_parquet")
```

I tried another example that has original data of month array and num array at the top level.  I can arrays_zip without flatten and get the same schema and data shown.  However, it output original field name correctly in this case.

I tried add alias to flatten data.  That does not  work. I even tried manipulate columns like (assume field store the result of arrays_zip is 'zipped'

```
val columns: Array[Column] = inner.fields.map(_.name).map{x => col("zipped").getField(x).alias(x)}
    val newB3 = newB2.withColumn("b", array(struct(columns:_*))).drop("zipped")
```

It ends up generate original schema ('month", array of string and "num", array of long).

To duplicate the problem, you can use the json input

```
"cal":[{"month":["Jan","Feb","Mar"],"num":[1,2,3]},{"month":["April"],"num":[4]}]}
```

the following json is for top-level arrays_zip

```
{"month":["Jan","Feb","Mar"],"num":[1,2,3]}
```

How Spark internally decide what field names to use?  How can I get it to work? Please advise.

Comment: Got the same problem. Looks like a bug to me, it sometimes uses columns names, depends on their struct. how did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 2.4, the schema transformation can be achieved using Higher Order Functions. In Scala the query can look like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, flatten}

val result = df
.withColumn("cal", flatten(expr("TRANSFORM(cal, x -> zip_with(x.month, x.num, (month, num) -> (month,num)))")))
```

After applying on your sample data i get this schema:

```
result.printSchema()
root
 |-- cal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- num: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks.   It looks promising.  I output to parquet.  It does keep original columns.  Interesting, arrays_zip directly on nested array does not work.  But will it work inside TRANSFORM?  A lot of possibility.

Comment: @user2200901 I tried arrays_zip inside TRANSFORM and it used names 1 and 0 for the cols.

Comment: K.   Columns are not static and are programmatically generated with defined variables.  arrays_zip is much convenient in this case. Therefore, I can try arrays_zip then manipulate with column alias or fold with zip_with.   Hopefully, I have spare time to try soon.  Thanks.